# Can d3.js graph put inside a table?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3.js, currently i am using this js to generate a graph. The graph is append to a `<div>`. I am wondering is it possible to put this graph inside a table? Thank you so much!

Comment: Tables should not be used for layout.  Put it in a <div> and position it with CSS instead.

Comment: In principle, there's nothing stopping you appending the graph to a `<td>` element, although as @duffymo points out, this is probably not the best idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The best way to do it is creating a [reusable chart](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/), create a selection with the cells, bind your dataset and invoke the chart using `selection.call`. You can even create the table with D3.

There is a number of valid reasons to put a chart inside a table. For instance, it can be useful to put [sparklines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparkline) in a table cell to complement the information given in each row.